# TYPO3: Backend Module render action of another Controller

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-extensions

I created a simple backend module for TYPO3 (7.6.15), with help of the ExtensionBuilder. The `UserController` and `MediaController` have a `createAction`, `showAction` and `listAction`. The `PanelController` just has the `showAction` which is the main view of the module and should look like this:

[image: Display of the PanelController.showAction]

Now, I want to render the `listActions` from the other controllers in the template of the `PanelController.showAction` and I would like to do it in the template of the view (`MyExt/Resources/Private/Templates/Panel/Show.html`), if possible.

I appreciate all help in advance and wish everyone a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I haven't even realized for years that the question was still open. I simply loaded both external controllers to get all the data I needed. Then I passed the data to the correct view templates within the view itself, which were the views of the original list actions.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Redirects the request to another action and / or controller.
 *
 * @param string $actionName Name of the action to forward to
 * @param string $controllerName Unqualified object name of the controller to forward to. If not specified, the current controller is used.
 * @param string $extensionName Name of the extension containing the controller to forward to. If not specified, the current extension is assumed.
 * @param array $arguments Arguments to pass to the target action
 * @param integer $pageUid Target page uid. If NULL, the current page uid is used
 * @param integer $delay (optional) The delay in seconds. Default is no delay.
 * @param integer $statusCode (optional) The HTTP status code for the redirect. Default is "303 See Other"
 */    
protected function redirect(
        $actionName,
        $controllerName = NULL,
        $extensionName = NULL,
        array $arguments = NULL,
        $pageUid = NULL, 
        $delay = 0, 
        $statusCode = 303
    )
```

You have to pass controller name and action name in redirect method to call action of another controller.

Please review above method that helps you.

or if you do it in template itself than may be you have to call viewhelper.

Comment: Where does this code go, and where is it called from?

Comment: That is not what I wanted,but for @nHaskins it can be called inside of any controller that inherits the `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController` with `$this->redirect('action', 'Controller');` but see the docs for _redirect_ and _forward_ [here](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_mvc_1_1_controller_1_1_abstract_controller.html#ac9e12bf23f76776a8b233713773d9de2)